# Find Closest Value from one SAS table to another

Tags: arrays, sas, lookup

having trouble resolving this problem in SAS, here is my data:

Table A: 3 columns

```
ID     COUNT       MEAN

A           2      0.034

B       4     -0.052

C       7      0.327

..  ..  ..
```

The ID variable is unique and the COUNT variable has a discrete range from 1-12.

Table B: 13 columns

```
CLUSTER  MEAN1  MEAN2  MEAN3  MEAN4  MEAN5  MEAN6  -->   MEAN12

1    0.344  0.234  0.233  ..     ..     ..     ..      ..    

2    0.234  0.234  0.343  ..     ..     ..     ..      ..
```

The CLUSTER variable currently ranges from 1-12 BUT IT IS NOT FIXED, so the code needs to 
be able to incorporate edge cases of when the number of clusters could differ.

Problem:
From Table A, I want to use the COUNT variable as a reference to find the closest
MEAN to the list of possible MEAN values from the corresponding MEAN(N)
from Table B, and then select the associated CLUSTER number from the row associated with
the closest match.

For example, ID 'A' has a COUNT of 2 and a MEAN of 0.034, so I would need to find the closest
mean value for that ID from the list of possible MEAN values from column MEAN2 in Table B.
I would need to do that for across 12 possible COUNT values and 12 MEAN columns.

Arrays and Indexing are out of my wheelhouse so any help would be appreciated,
Brandon

Comment: Please show any attempts you 've tried and exactly what you would expect as output. It would help to align a small example, that fully illustrates your issue, showing both the input and the matched output for that input. See the guidelines on how to ask a question here: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

The lookup becomes much easier if you transpose the cluster means into this layout

```
Cluster Count Mean
1       1     0.344
1       2     0.234
1       3     0.233
…
2       1     0.234
2       2     0.234
2       3     0.343
…
```

You can then use SQL to select the closest cluster mean to your observed means

```
    select 
      id,
      clusters_tall.cluster,
      clusters_tall.mean as cluster_mean,
      observed.mean - clusters_tall.mean as delta
    from 
      observed 
    join 
      clusters_tall 
    on 
      observed.count = clusters_tall.count
    group by 
      observed.id
    having 
      abs(observed.mean - clusters_tall.mean) = min (abs (observed.mean - clusters_tall.mean))
```

Example:

```
* create some sample data for clusters;
data clusters;
  do cluster = 1 to 50;
    array mean(12);
    call missing (of mean(*));
    do _n_ = 1 to ceil(12*ranuni(123));
      mean(_n_) = round(ranuni(123),0.0001);
    end;
    output;
  end;
run;

* create some sample data for observed;
* 60% of the id will be given a mean close to a randomly selected (picked) existing cluster mean;
data observed (keep=id count mean pick flag);
  length id count mean 8.;

  do id = 1 to 1000;
    pick = ceil(50*ranuni(123));

    point = pick;
    set clusters point=point;

    mean = .;

    if ranuni(123) < 0.6 then do until (not missing(mean));
      array means mean1-mean12;
      flag = '*';
      count = ceil(12 * ranuni(123));
      if not missing(means(count)) then 
        mean = means(count) + round((ranuni(123)-0.5) / 1e3,0.0001); 
    end;
    else do;
      flag = 'R';
      count = ceil (12 * ranuni(123));
      mean = round(ranuni(123),0.001) + 0.0005;
    end;

    output;
  end;
  stop;
run;

* use data step to transpose the 'wide' form of cluster data into the 'cluster/count/mean' layout;;
data clusters_tall(keep=cluster count mean);
  set clusters;
  array means mean1-mean12;
  do _n_ = 1 to dim(means) while (not missing(means(_n_)));
    count = _n_;
    mean = means(_n_);
    output;
  end;
run;

* match the observed mean to the closest cluster mean;
* inner join in sub-select is used to get closest cluster, but there could be
* more than one cluster with same closest state.;
* Thus, left join to the sub-select and chose the one
* with the lowest cluster number in case of a tie;

proc sql;
  create table observed_matched(label="Observed matched to cluster with closest mean") as

  select observed.*, matched.cluster, matched.cluster_mean, matched.delta
  from

  observed
  left join 
  ( 
    select 
      id,
      clusters_tall.cluster,
      clusters_tall.mean as cluster_mean,
      observed.mean - clusters_tall.mean as delta
    from 
      observed 
    join 
      clusters_tall 
    on 
      observed.count = clusters_tall.count
    group by 
      observed.id
    having 
      abs(observed.mean - clusters_tall.mean) = min (abs (observed.mean - clusters_tall.mean))
  ) as matched

  on observed.id = matched.id
  group by observed.id
  having cluster = min(cluster)
  order by id, cluster
  ;
```